# Pandas perform functions using multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes in Python, one only has one row of data. The other has many rows. I would like to go through each row of the first one and subtract the second one from it. I would then like to store the results in a dataframe the size of the second one. The first one is

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Amounts": [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]})
```

And the second one is

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [500, 600, 700, 800, 900], 
                    "B": [250, 750, 900, 500, 200], 
                    "C": [450, 125, 600, 200, 800]})
```

I am trying to subtract one from the other (1.1 from A, 2.2 from B, 3.3 from C) to get the following output:

```
A     B    C
[498.9, 247.8, 446.7],
[598.9, 747.8, 121.7],
[698.9, 897.8, 596.7],
[798.9, 497.8, 196.7],
[898.9, 197.8, 796.7]
```

And save it as another dataframe. Any assistance you could provide would be very helpful!  Bonus points if you could also provide an answer for similar arithmetic (i.e. multplying instead of subtracting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `df1` to Series and to numpy array to bypass index alignment:

```
df3 = df2.sub(df1['Amounts'].to_numpy(), axis=1)
```

There are many alternative, like full numpy:

```
df3 = df2.sub(df1.to_numpy().ravel(), axis=1)
```

Or full pandas:

```
df3 = df2.sub(df1['Amounts'].set_axis(df2.columns), axis=1)
```

output:

```
       A      B      C
0  498.9  247.8  446.7
1  598.9  747.8  121.7
2  698.9  897.8  596.7
3  798.9  497.8  196.7
4  898.9  197.8  796.7
```

Comment: The full pandas option worked great, thanks!  It also turns out there was an issue with the csv I was reading in for df2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Amounts": [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [500, 600, 700, 800, 900], 
                "B": [250, 750, 900, 500, 200], 
                "C": [450, 125, 600, 200, 800]})

final = pd.DataFrame()
if len(df1) != len(df2.columns):
     pass
else:
   for i in range(len(df1)):
       final[df2.columns[i]]=df2[df2.columns[i]].astype(float)-df1['Amounts'] [i].astype(float)

final



   A    B   C
0   498.9   247.8   446.7
1   598.9   747.8   121.7
2   698.9   897.8   596.7
3   798.9   497.8   196.7
4   898.9   197.8   796.7
```